# How to convert CMD to JSON array correctly in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I am trying to convert the following command into JSON Array.

From this

```
CMD $(npm bin)/knex migrate:latest && $(npm bin)/knex seed:run && npm run start
```

To this

```
CMD ["$(npm bin)/knex", "migrate:latest", "&&", "$(npm bin)/knex", "seed:run", "&&", "npm", "run", "start"]
```

But it gives me this error. It seems the be the problem of path.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/$(npm bin)/knex'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Why is that? This is my dockerfile config

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 8080

COPY ./package*.json /

RUN ["npm", "install"]

COPY ./. /

#  CMD $(npm bin)/knex migrate:latest && $(npm bin)/knex seed:run && npm run start

CMD ["$(npm bin)/knex", "migrate:latest", "&&", "$(npm bin)/knex", "seed:run", "&&", "npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: Did you try adding them into a file like `cm.sh` and add this file into the container, then use `CMD ["/cm.sh"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the specific question you asked: there are two forms of `CMD` (and `ENTRYPOINT` and `RUN`).  The [JSON-array form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) is interpreted directly, without running a shell or performing any sort of expansion; [anything else](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) is interpreted as though it was run with `sh -c`.

```sh
# the same:
CMD any command string
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "any command string"]
```

In the command you show, you *must* run some shell to perform the `$(npm bin)` subshell expansion, and to run multiple `command1 && command2`.  You could manually wrap the command string you show in the JSON-array `["sh", "-c", "..."]` form, but there's no real benefit to it.  With that specific `CMD`, the form you have in the question is the best you can do.

---

This having been said, if you have a very involved `CMD` like this, you might consider whether you can break it up into smaller parts.  The commands you show do some first-time setup, and then launch the main container command.  You can turn this into a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
#
# Do the first-time setup:
npx knex migrate:latest
npx knex seed:run

# Launch the main container command:
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, `COPY` this script into your image (if it's not already there) and set it as your `ENTRYPOINT`.  You also need to provide the `CMD` to run.  With both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, [the `CMD` is passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and so the final `exec "$@"` line runs the `CMD`.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .           # if it's not already copied in
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array form
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]    # either JSON-array or string form
```

One thing that's useful to do with this setup is to launch a temporary container with a debugging shell:

```sh
docker run --rm -it your-image /bin/sh
```

This replaces the `CMD`, but leaves the `ENTRYPOINT` intact.  This runs the wrapper script and does the first-time setup (in this case, the database migrations), but then launches the shell instead of your application.  Now you can check what's actually happened in the setup phase and debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I split them into `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, will ENTRYPOINT run once during build time only? Or it will run at run time?

Comment: btw that debug tip is really useful! thanks

Comment: When the container runs, it runs a single command, that is made by combining the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` into a single command line.  Said differently, `ENTRYPOINT` runs once at container startup as the main container command, and it is given `CMD` as arguments.